# cannot install multicomp package after upgrade R to 3.5.1

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried to install multicomp package after I upgrade my R to 3.5.1.

```
install.packages('multicomp',dependency=TRUE,repos='http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/')
```

I got error message:

```
package ‘multicomp’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

I tried many different mirrors, but nothing works for me.

Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to install package multcomp (without i)?

Comment: sorry, what a stupid question.  Thank you for your answer!